# Converting Multiple JSON into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple JSONs and I would like to convert to an array of objects.

```
peopleJSONData = 
    {"name":"Nicholas","age":"30"}
    {"name":"Daniel","age":45"}
```

I would like to convert it to an array of objects in JavaScript.

```
peopleArrayObjects = 
    [
        {name: "Nicholas", age: 30}
        {name: "Daniel", age: 45}
    ]

Please help! :)
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+objects+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: 1. JSON is a text representation of a POJO (plain old JavaScript Object) so you do not have "A JSON" or "MULTIPLE JSONs" unless you have JSON encoded strings   - 2. your input is not valid JS. Please post a better example

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work :

```js
const peopleArrayObjects = [];

peopleArrayObjects.push(JSON.parse(peopleJSONData));
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple JSON Objects, I assume it would be in a different variable. Like

```
var json1 = {"name":"Nicholas","age":"30"};
    
var json2 = {"name":"Daniel","age":45"};
```

What you can do is :

```
let peopleArrayObjects = [];
peopleArrayObjects.push(json1);
peopleArrayObjects.push(json2);
```

AND if you have a single JSON having multiple

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object. THIS is a JSON string: `const json1 = '{"name":"Nicholas","age":"30"}';` and this is a POJO - Plain Old JavaScript Object: `const obj1 = {"name":"Nicholas","age":"30"};`

Comment: I am getting multiple JSONs because of POSTMAN get request